# Как изменить HTML тег на сайте с помощью Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html5, selenium

Есть сайт, в HTML коде которого есть тег `<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-08dd3nfdjb3v" name="g-recaptcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea>`. Мне нужно, чтобы был удален атрибут `style` и получился такой тег: `<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-08dd3nfdjb3v" name="g-recaptcha-response"></textarea>`.
Сайт мне не принадлежит, HTML код я беру с помощью кода страницы. Вручную я открываю код страницы, ищу данный тег, изменяю его, сохраняю. Как сделать то же самое, но с помощью Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на подобный вопрос ([оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830954/how-can-i-change-remove-style-attibute-with-selenium-python)) c применением `Selenium` :

`[id^=g-recaptcha-response]` *ищет совпадения по началу id*

> `driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('[id^=g-recaptcha-response]').style.display = 'block';")`

Вот небольшой пример кода как это можно сделать вручную.

1. открыть сайт
2. нажать F12
3. открыть внизу вкладку Console
4. вставить эти 2 строки

   `const textarea = document.querySelector('[id^=g-recaptcha-response]'); textarea.removeAttribute('style');`
5. нажать Enter

Тут кнопка демонстрирует работу

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  const textarea = document.querySelector('[id^=g-recaptcha-response]')
  textarea.removeAttribute('style');
}, false)
```

```html
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-08dd3nfdjb3v" name="g-recaptcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea>
<button id="btn">удалить стиль</button>
```

Comment: То есть я должен зайти на сайт и в консоль вставить вот это - `const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

  // нужно скопировать эти 2 строки
  const textarea = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response-08dd3nfdjb3v")
  textarea.removeAttribute('style');

}, false)`?

Comment: Или только это - `const textarea = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response-08dd3nfdjb3v")
  textarea.removeAttribute('style');`?

Comment: да последний вариант

Comment: @kfcgenius сейчас посмотрю как по селениуму сделать, у Вас есть кусок кода начальный, который можно было добавить в вопрос?

Comment: @kfcgenius я дополнил ответ примером для селениума, к сожалению сам не смогу проверить, но выглядит убедительно. Cделать `display = 'block'` все равно что отобразить элемент

Comment: Добавил весь код

Comment: Вставил Ваш вариант в `solve_captcha` после проверки на ошибки, но вывелась ошибка `Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Comment: @kfcgenius вероятно id меняется, можно искать по его началу (оно не меняется), я доработал ответ

Comment: Вы гений, спасибо

Comment: А можно у Вас еще 1 вопрос спросить? Этот атрибут удалялся, чтобы появилось поле ввода текста, чтобы в него вставить ключ от решенной капчи, чтобы потом просто нажать на капчу и она решилась. Но проблема в том, что на капчу нажать не получается. Вы не знаете, что можно сделать?

Comment: Я ищу капчу с селениумом через xpath, чтобы на нее нажать

Comment: неглядя не скажу, но в целом селениумом можно генерить клики мышью, но я с этим почти не работал.